# Exponents, versus Exponentials, versus Exponential Functions. Splitting hairs on definitions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function, definition, exponentiation

I stumbled upon some tutorial videos on various topic in math by [Lorenzo Stadun](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC3IZYipZ6A_Rs5v0GdwUM7Q/featured).  I'm sharing the link because a cursory glance indicates that the content is pretty good.  So the first thing I ever do with something I like is to criticize it.

In his first pre-calculus review video on logarithms he says
$x=\log_a\left(y\right)$ is the *inverse exponential* of $y=a^x,$ where $y=a^x$ means $y$ is *the exponential of* $x$.

If someone tells me to write $y$ as the exponential of $x$, I will write $y=\exp\left(x\right)$ which means $y=\exp\left(x\right)=e^x.$  In other words, ***the** exponential,* and ***the** exponential function* explicitly mean Euler's number $e$ raised to a specified power.

I would say $a^x$ is an exponential expression, meaning that it involves an exponent.  I say $y=a^x$ means $y$ equals $a$ raised to the power $x,$ or $a$ (to the) exponent $x$.

**What is the standard usage for these terms?**

### Edit to add:

One place where ***the** exponential function* specifically means $y=e^x\iff \ln y=x$ is **§8-8 The Exponential Function** of Calculus and Analytic Geometry: With Supplementary Problems, Second Edition, by Thomas, George B., 1953.  That is the same Thomas as in Thomas's Calculus, 14th Edition.

In that context *the exponential function* is defined as

$$y=e^x\iff \ln y=x\backepsilon{x\in\mathbb{R}}.$$

Prior to that point $e^q$ was only defined for rational numbers $q$, and was not called the exponential function.  Thomas does give the full name as "the exponential function, with $e$ as base and exponent $x$."  But continues to discuss $e^x$ as "the exponential function," without qualification.

As was pointed out in the comments, we can always change the base, so all real number expressions involving exponents can be written in the form $e^x$ using the **definition** $a^u=e^{u\ln{a}},$ which Thomas gives in **§8-9 The Function $a^u.$**

Comment: Where is the $x$? As exponent, so it's an *exponential* expression

Comment: I seriously doubt there are standard uses, and phrasings will greatly depend on context (school algebra vs. calculus and analysis vs. Lie group theory etc.) and on the language background of the writer (much of mathematics in English is written by non-native English speakers, meaning your emphasis on **the** is often not observed).

Comment: From a certain point of view, there really is only one exponential, as any two exponentials only differ by a constant scaling.

Comment: It is quite common that $e^{x}$ and $\ln x$ are _natural_ exponential and _natural_ inverse exponential or _natural_ logarithmic functions. For other bases, I don't have an idea about the terminology. The reason for this is from derivatives, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: For me, an [exponential function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4432035/21813) is one that is proportional to its derivative or, equivalently, a function $f$ such that for some nonzero $k,\:f(x)=ae^{kx}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard usage for the term **exponential** by itself, it is usually used with other terms, like exponential growth, exponential function, etc.

The standard usage for **exponential function** is, as you correctly noted, $e^x$, if nothing is meant by context. However, sometimes $a^x$ may also be called an exponential function for some $a\ne e$ (the point to be noted is that $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$, so one is just a $x$-scaled version of other function).

**Exponent**, as you again correctly noted, is just the power of a number (for example, $2$ is the exponent and 3 is the base in $3^2$).

Hope it helps:)

Comment: What I am talking about regarding *the exponential* meaning $exp\left(\dots\right),$ and *the exponential function* meaning $e^\lambda$ may be more common to physics than mathematics.  See https://store.doverpublications.com/0486652270.html and https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781316276105 for examples.