# Help me understand what is and isn't exponential growth.

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

If the rate at which something grows is proportional to itself, then you would call it exponential growth. Don't quote me on this, but I think it has something of the form $y = e^x$.

Now take for example this. If you want to calculate the volume of a sphere, the formula is $v = 4/3 π r^3$ . The derivative with respect to the radius is $dv/dr = 4πr^2$. This shows the rate of change of the volume with respect to the radius.

Yet the volume of the sphere is proportional to the radius, which in turn defines the size of the sphere. The rate at which the volume of the sphere increases is proportional to itself in a way. Intuitively, I would expect to find somewhere in there an exponential yet there isn't. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You are considering the function $V(r)$ which gives you the volume of a sphere of radius $r$. The rate of change $V'$ of this function *depends* on $V$, but it is not *proportional* to $V$. We have $V(r)=\frac43\pi r^3$ and thus $V'(r)=4\pi r^2=4\pi(\frac43\pi)^{\frac32}[V(r)]^\frac{2}{3}$. So $V'$ is proportional to $V^\frac{2}{3}$, not to $V$. Which is why we shouldn't expect anything exponential here.

Getting back to the beginning, I think your core misconception is "proportional = dependent on". This is not so. Proportionality is a very specific and special kind of dependence, and there are a huge variety of ways in which two things can depend on each other without it being proportional.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may be confusing the concepts "is proportional to" and "is an *increasing function* of". The volume of the sphere increases as the radius increases, but they are not directly proportional. Rather, the volume of the radius is proportional to the *cube* of the radius, or $V = kr^3$ for some constant $k > 0$. In this case, that specific constant is $4\pi/3 \approx 4.18879$. If the radius were increasing with time (say, at a given constant rate), then the volume would also increase with time according to

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dV}{dr} \cdot \frac{dr}{dt} = 4\pi r^2 \cdot \frac{dr}{dt}.$$

And since the volume is determined by the radius, we can say the radius is conversely determined by the volume, according to $r = aV^{1/3}$ for some constant $a$ (ignoring for the moment to focus on the proportionality relationships). If the radius were increasing at a constant rate (if $dr/dt$ were a constant), then the above equation simplifies to

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = b V^{2/3}$$

for some constant $b$. So we see that the rate of change of the volume is proportional not to the volume *itself*, but a fractional power of the volume. So it is indeed the case that they *increase together* - as the volume goes up, the rate at which the volume is increasing also goes up - but they are not directly proportional. You can imagine in this case that you have something like "diminishing returns": you can increase $V$ all you like to increase $dV/dt$ arbitrarily high, but proportionally, the increase will be less and less the higher that $V$ climbs.

Compare to true exponential growth: say $y(t) = e^{rt}$ for some $r > 0$. Then in this case, we have

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = re^{rt} = ry$$

and so the rate of change truly is proportional to the quantity itself, not some greater or lesser power than the quantity. This is the hallmark of exponential growth. We also see that they increase together (as one goes up, the other also goes up), but more strongly is the fact that they are *directly proportional*, or their ratio is constant. You can increase $y$ all you like and $dy/dt$ will increase in lock-step, by exactly the same multiplier, independent of the size of $y$. This situation contrasts with the one above.

Answer (score 0):

> If the rate at which something grows is proportional to itself, then you would call it exponential growth.

This is exactly correct.

An **exponential function** is one whose rate of change is proportional to the function; in other words, a function that is undergoing a constant percentage change (growth/shrinkage/decay).

> Don't quote me on this, but I think it has something of the form $y = e^x$.

Yes. Every exponential function of $x$ can be written as $$ab^{cx}$$ for some $b\in(0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$ and nonzero $c,$ or simply $$ae^{kx}$$ for some nonzero $k.$

The function's derivative is proportional to the function, with proportionality constant $c\ln(b)$ or $k,$ respectively.

> the formula for the volume of a sphere is $v = 4/3 π r^3.$
>
> the volume of the sphere is proportional to the radius.

No: the sphere's volume $\dfrac 43 π r^3$ is proportional not to its radius but to *the cube of its radius*.

> The derivative with respect to the radius is $dv/dr = 4πr^2$.
>
> The rate at which the volume of the sphere increases is proportional in a way.

No: the volume's derivative $4πr^2$ is proportional not to the volume but to *the volume raised to the* $\frac23.$

P.S. $f(x)$ being proportional to $g(x)$ means that $f(x)=k\times g(x)$ for some nonzero $k.$